# Is this <?php //comment ?> kind of comment workable in php?

Tags: php, comments

I'm trying to add comment in php line.
But I don't know if a close tag `?>` stay in the same line with //comment will work.

for example `<?php function() {//comment ?>` 
will the //comment will make `?>` not avaliable?

Comment: Seems like you could try it pretty quickly and find out.

Comment: Sure, it works fine. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes you can use a single line comment like this <?php // comment?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `//` and `#` style comments `?>` will close the PHP block as well as the comment. With `/* ... */` style comments it will not:

```
<?php # Closing PHP tag closes comment AND PHP block ?>
<?php // Closing PHP tag closes comment AND PHP block ?>
<?php /* Closing PHP tag DOES not close comment AND PHP block ?> */ ?>
```

Edit: Syntax highlighting here is wrong, the PHP block isn't closed until the last one.

Answer (score 0):

As [you can test yourself](http://ideone.com/BV5KM), this works fine.

php parses everything between `<?php` and `?>` according to the normal parsing rules.